# Understanding how amazon Autoscale will Autoscale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I've been setting a prestashop server architecture on amazon aws since 3 days and now everything is up and running. I have an ELB, RDS and an auto-scaling group set up with alarm (add one instance if cpu > 80% ).
I have only ONE instance that runs my prestashop website, attached to an extra EBS volume where I uploaded the website.

Now what I don't understand is how auto-scaling will act if the CPU is greater that 80%?
Will it create automatically a new instance that is the exact copy of the running instance?
If yes then will it copy also the attached EBS volume? Because I add product everyday, so if a new instance is created it HAVE to be the exact same as the original one otherwise customers won't find the new products they came for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use autoscaling your instances have to be stateless. When AS group is scaling out, it winds up an instance from an AMI you have set in AS launch configuration.

It will be the exact copy if this image, not of an instance that is already running.

State (products, sessions, whatnot) should be stored elsewhere, in some DB for example (you have mentioned RDS).

Comment: Yes but this doesn't answer the main question: what happens to my attached Volume, will it be replicated  ? If not what is the solution , because auto-scaling to have 2 different website version is so dramatically stupid !! People have to find the same products whether they are in the main instance or in the new instance created by auto-scale, so how you folks solve this problem ?

Comment: an instance is started using AMI. you can update the instance on start up, getting new version of your app etc. as i have said you have to make stateless app and keep your state elsewhere, as with aws auto scaling your instances will be created and terminated according to AS policies and your triggers.

Comment: How could you make a prestashop ecommerce website stateless ? During the day, you'll add products or change stuff in the website and suddenly CPU goes to 80% and autoscale launch  a new instance. So i have no chance to update the AMI before. Is there an automated way to make autoscale make a new Image before creating an instance ? How you guys do concretely with ecommerce websites ?

Comment: save stuff that changes elsewhere. db is this elsewhere. s3 is this elsewhere.

Comment: autoscaling is not a magic trick that makes all your troubles disappear. it has it's limitations.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to set a "media server" in s3. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup will not work, since each container running in the cluster needs to share certain directories amongst each other. This is because PrestaShop v1.7 at the time of writing stores certain stateful information in the file system.

I feel the accepted answer is incorrect. Rather, "To use autoscaling it is **best** that your instances are stateless" - but it's not a hard requirement. To this point, I've successfully run PrestaShop in an autoscaling ECS cluster by storing certain shared directories on EFS, and then mounting those directories from each container running in the cluster. The directories that need to be shared are:

- Img
- Modules
- Override
- Cache
- Theme
- Config

More information along with code can be found [here](https://www.hadii.ca/insights/scalable-prestashop).